# Regex for matching just the first occurrence of a comma in each line

Tags: regex, notepad++

What does the regex look like for matching only the first instance of a comma, and nothing but that comma?

I have tried things like `,{1}` and I think it has something to do with non-greedy qualifiers like this `,(.*?)`, but I have had no success.

I'm using Notepad++ to try to convert code from another language to JavaScript.  I want to turn the first comma into a colon.  It looks like this:

```
'TJ', 'Tajikistan' ,
'TZ', 'Tanzania' ,
'TH', 'Thailand' ,
'TL', 'Timor-Leste' ,
'TG', 'Togo' ,
'TK', 'Tokelau' ,
'TO', 'Tongo' ,
'TT', 'Trinidad and Tobago' ,
```

Find what: `/,/`
Replace with: `:`
0 occurrences were replaced

[image: Screnshot of Notepad++]

Comment: Just use `/,/`, without the `/g`?

Comment: Your regex works. So follow Qtax's advice

Comment: why not `string.indexOf(',')` ?

Comment: As @acdcjunior said, use `string.indexOf(',')` with a combination of `substr` or suchlike if possible, `regex` is slower.

Comment: Oops, I shouldn't have mentioned javascript.  In reality, I'm formatting something to javascript on notepad++.  I'm using the ctrl+f replace all, and I need to replace the first comma with a colon.

Comment: If you're just trying to replace the first comma, why use "replace all"? Heck, why even use "replace"?

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to replace the first comma *on each line*. That's a bit different. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more clear.  Sorry about that

Comment: Why is @user1864610 being so obnoxious? Why not be helpful and friendly to people, even if they are doing something contrary to the conventions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you can do is, instead of just replacing the first comma with a colon, you can automatically replace the comma *and everything after it* with the colon *plus everything that was after the comma*. (For example, in `'TZ', 'Tanzania' ,`, this approach would replace `, 'Tanzania' ,` with `: 'Tanzania' ,`.) After that, since the rest of the line has already undergone replacement, Notepad++ doesn't re-examine it to see whether it contains a comma.

The way you do that is by using a *capture group*, which lets the replacement-string incorporate part of what the regex matched.

Specifically, you would replace this ("Find what"):

```
,(.*)
```

meaning "a comma (`,`), plus zero or more characters (`.*`), and capture the latter (`()`)", with this ("Replace with"):

```
:$1
```

meaning "a colon (`:`), plus whatever was captured by the first capture group (`$1`)".

Comment: brilliant.  how does this work?

Comment: @Parseltongue: In the regex, `(.*)` means "zero or more non-newline characters -- and 'capture' them (i.e., remember them for later reference)". In the replacement-string, `$1` means "the stuff you captured". (If you have multiple sets of `(...)`, then you can also have `$2`, `$3`, etc.) So this works by replacing a comma, plus the rest of the line, with a colon, plus the rest of the line. After that, since the rest of the line has already undergone replacement, Notepad++ doesn't re-examine it to see if it contains a comma.

Comment: Thnaks so much for the explanation